# ASP.NET delete item in a paged container

Tags: asp.net

I am currently building a CRUD operations on a entity called Payment.
When are click the pages, for instance, page 2, and try to delete the 9th item on page 2,
it will delete the 9th item on page 1 for me.
Here is my code:

```
protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    int paymentId = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    try
    {
        using (BillingApplicationDataContext dc = new BillingApplicationDataContext())
        {
             BLLPayment bllCorporation = new BLLPayment(dc);
             bllCorporation.DeletePayment(paymentId);
        }
        Response.RedirectToRoute("ViewPaymentsRoute");
    }
    catch
    {
        Response.RedirectToRoute("ErrorPageRoute", new { 
             ErrorMsg = "Unable to delete Payment with Id " + 
                         paymentId.ToString() + "." });
    }
}

<asp:ListView ID="lstPayment" runat="server" OnPagePropertiesChanging="lstPayment_PagePropertiesChanging" 
       EnableViewState="false">
  <LayoutTemplate>
       <fieldset>
           <legend>View Payments</legend>
               <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                   <tr>
                      <th>Id</th>
                      <th>Corporation</th>
                      <th>Service Contract</th>
                      <th>Payment Date</th>
                      <th>Payment Amount</th>
                   </tr>
                   <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
                </table>
         </fieldset>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
         <tr>
             <td><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id")%>' EnableViewState="false"/></td>
                    <td><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CorpName")%>' EnableViewState="false"/></td>
                    <td><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ServiceContractName")%>' EnableViewState="false"/></td>
                    <td><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PaymentDate")%>' EnableViewState="false" /></td>
                    <td><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Amount")%>' EnableViewState="false" /></td>
                    <td>
                    <%--<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Detail" 
                    OnCommand="btnDetail_Click" 
                    CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id")%>' EnableViewState="true"/>--%>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" Text="Delete" runat="server"
                    oncommand='btnDelete_Click' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>'
                    OnClientClick="return ConfirmDelete();"/></td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
        <asp:DataPager ID="dataPager" runat="server" PagedControlID="lstPayment" EnableViewState="true">
            <Fields>
                <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonType="Link" />
            </Fields>
        </asp:DataPager>
        <asp:Button runat="server" 
        ID="btnNew" 
        oncommand='btnNew_Click'
        Text="New"/>
```

I think there may be something wrong with the page life cycle, but I do not know how to trace.

Answer (score 0):

Why have you commented out

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Detail" 
                OnCommand="btnDetail_Click" 
                **CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id")%>'** EnableViewState="true"/>
```

You are trying to retreive the paymentId but you are passing Id as the command argument. I think the line above is absolutely correct.